# how to hide "Apache-Coyote/1.1" on tomcat 5.0.28

Tags: apache

I want to hide server information "Apache-Coyote/1.1" when I execute  `curl -i ip:port` command in my tomcat 5.0.28.

I tried to add `<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" server="Apache">` to server.xml file. but it doesn't work.

I tested it on tomcat 5.5, 6 and 7. in this case, It's works all find. But it doesn't work my tomcat(5.0.28 ver).

How can I hide this in my tomcat 5.0.28.

Thanks.

Comment: I thinsk it's not possible below 5.0. It's possible above 5.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinsk it's not possible below 5.0. It's possible above 5.5.